# How can I merge Object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

This is two object. One is 'major'. Other one is 'marjorModel'.

```
const major = [
  {
    id: 1,
    subject: 'math',
    title: 'no good'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    subject: 'science',
    title: 'good'
  }
]

const majorModel = [
 {
   id: 1,
   amount: 23,
   date: '2022-03-01'
 },
 {
   id: 3,
   amount: 26,
   date: '2022-03-01'
 }
]
```

and I want to merge new one

example)

```
const newObj = [
 {
  id: 1,
  subject: 'math',
  title: 'no good',
  amount: 23,
  date: '2022-03-01'
 },
 {
  id: 2,
  subject: 'science',
  title: 'good',
  amount: 26,
  date: '2022-03-01'
 }
]
```

I don't know how to merge different of other object.
please let me know!!

Comment: So what happened with  `id: 3`?

Comment: Ooops... that's my fault... thx a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use reduce

```
major.reduce((acc, v, i) => {
  acc.push({
    ...v,
    ...majorModel[i]
  });
  return acc;
}, []);
```